# Animate walking on a ground

Tags: animation

I'm a total beginner in blender, but I already managed to make an object with Material, UVMaps etc. 
My Figure consists out of multpile Objects, and I made 'set parent' so I could move them correctly in my Animation.
But I want to add a ground to my world, something my figure can walk upon.
Is there an option in Blender to make objects not go through each other. So that my figure walks on the ground, and that even if I am animating it, it won't touch the ground, just like in real life when you walk.

I know I wrote a lot here, I just hope you got my problem, here's the link of the Figure I made (exactly like in the video).

W.Zayde [1]: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKP3Ij6WkoU

Comment: you could probably see this contraint https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/relationship/floor.html